# Google Apps Script - Send Email with Edit Link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am creating a script that sends a custom email right after you send the form. It works perfectly but I wanted it to work also when I edit the form it sends a automatic email with the changes made.

```
  function Initialize() {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers)
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

        ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")

    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onFormSubmit().create();
}

function SendGoogleForm(e) {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "Please paste this!\n\n";
  var subject = "Email: ID: ";
  var email = "";
  //
  var form = FormApp.openById('*******************'); //this is the ID in the url of your live form
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
//
   for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];

 }
  for(var i in headers) {
  if ( e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() != "") {
     message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n";  
  }
   }

  subject += e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString();
  email += e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString();
  message += "Edit Link: " + formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  }
```

I've found a script that may help to send a email when it is edited but I am not sure how I can implement it(found it in google docs forums https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/-guIl5QlvKk):

```
function checkResponse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var range = s.getRange('A' + lastRow + ':C' + lastRow);
  var notes = range.getNotes();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var changedFlag = null;
  var body = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < notes[0].length; i++ ) {
    if ( notes[0][i] == 'Responder updated this value.' ) {
      changedFlag = true;
      // We know only to send the changed values

      // Add changed value to email msg
      body += values[0][i];

      // May also want to clear the note as it remains after future edits of other values as well
      s.getRange(lastRow, i).clearNote();
    } 
  }

  if ( !changedFlag ) {
    // Email the whole row of values 
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      body += values[0][i];
    }
  }

  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
}
```

Comment: Anyone can give a hand?